# Git Clone Multiple Repository's into one developer repository

Tags: git, github

I am trying to setup a personal git repository example: jnew. Inside that repository I wan't to have many clones of other repository's. For example I have a repository called jnew and then inside there I wan't to have a clone called depot. My attempt at this was the following.

1. Create repository ex. jnew
2. Create local directory ex. /User/jnew/development/jnew
3. cd /User/jnew/development/jnew
4. git init
5. git remote add https://github.com/jnew/jnew.git
6. git clone --mirror https://github.com/jnew/depot.git depot
7. git remote add depot git@github.com:jnew/depot.git
8. git co -b 1234-test depot/verified-next

This all works except for the clone part. I would expect clone to bring in all branches from that remote repository so on github I could go into the depot directory then the branch to view the latest code. For some reason every time I try this the remote branches are not brought it. An example remote branch is verified which is a copy of the master branch.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. I have searched for hours on Google and here and have not found the answer as why the clone doesn't have the branches included in it.

If this is not making sense then can you explain a good approach in details. Meaning with git commands of how you would setups an individual developer to be able to work on multiple projects from within their own repository. This would be done to avoid mistakes pushing to the wrong repository.

Comment: I want to be able to manage multiple projects from one central repository this repository would be a development repository that is sort of a sandbox. Then when I am happy with my changes to whatever project I could merge my branch into the cloned repository. It's a way to keep things clean rather than have multiple developers use the same repository and pushing and branching from it.

Comment: Why do you insist so much on using one single repository to manage it all? Git repos are cheap and meant to be ubiquitous. The general guideline is: put into one repo what belongs together; if it doesnt belong with the other stuff, put it in another repo.

Answer (score 3):

You need [git-submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules). Submodules are solving the exact problem you have.

Comment: From my experience with git-submodule isn't that tied to a specific branch. For example if I have a repo that is called depot and I git submodule add git://github.com/jnew/whatever.git whatever that submodule wil be tied to whatever branch I was on like master? So if I create a new branch or have existing branches that submodule that I created will not exist when browsing those other branches? Also will update automatically when a git remote update is done like a clone would?