# How to Fork a project and then create another fork project inside that fork project

Tags: git, github, fork, git-submodules

I'm new in GitHub and I want to fork a project. Within that forked project, I need to create another forked project.

For visulaization, here's what I need:

```
FORKEDPROJECT1
    |
    |
    |
    SUB-FORKEDPROEJCT2
    |
    |changes on forkproject1
    |.....
```

how am I going to make this?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like forkception to me..

Comment: really? oh. I thought this can be done :(

Comment: You can click fork on your forked repository just like when you first forked the repository...if that makes any sense :P

Comment: Do this on the original project: https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo Then go to your forked copy of that repository (should be `github.com/your-username/forked-repo-name`) and click the fork button again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forking a project means the copy of same repository. Just like you copy a file from one location to other location. So forking a git repository copies that repository to your account. And each time you fork a project a new repository will be created with the source of repository being forked.
So, in your case

- fork the project
- make changes you want
- fork again whenever you want to

Comment: thanks. for example i already forked project 1, and inside forked project 1, I will forked another project, its like a subcomponent of forked project1. Can you show me how can this happen? I'm new in GIT and Github

Comment: Are you talking about nesting projects?
You mean you forked project 1, and then you want to fork project 2 inside project 1.

Comment: I think this is not possible. But you can clone multiple projects.
see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13707997/git-clone-multiple-repositorys-into-one-developer-repository

Comment: yes sir,. is that possible? the project2 will be a subcomponent of project1. I saw a function called submodule, but im not sure if this will help. If its not doable, how can I make them inside a project repo? thanks! I really appreciated your response.

Comment: its not forkedproject2, instead, submoduled the project2 from other source. thanks!